# Migrating for Django-Oscar-Accounts gives an error message

Tags: python, django, django-oscar

I followed the instructions given in the documentation for Django oscar accounts found [here](https://github.com/django-oscar/django-oscar-accounts) and installed Django Oscar accounts using `pip install django-oscar-accounts`, then I added oscar_accounts to my INSTALLED_APPS. then I ran the command `./manage.py migrate oscar_accounts`, after this I get the error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'oscar_accounts'
```

so in my settings.py file I changed `oscar_accounts` to `accounts`, then when I run the same manage.py command I get the error:

```
File "/project_path/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/accounts/abstract_models.py", line 5, in <module>
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django.core.urlresolvers'
```

How do I solve this?
I am using Django-oscar 1.6.1 and python 3.6

Comment: You probably should install it with `pip3`: `pip` is for Python-2.x

Comment: I just tried it and didn't work, still the same issue.

Comment: What version of Django are you running? It looks like you're using Django 2, which is not compatible with the current version of django-oscar-accounts.

Comment: Yes, it is Django 2.0, can you suggest any other library that could be used?

Comment: I've just released a new version of django-oscar-accounts that is Django 2 compatible.